# After creating the tutorial package beginner_tutorials, the package cannot be found later

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the beginner tutorials and I just created the package beginner_tutorials in the last tutorial, but now when I use roscd I get an error message that the package cannot be found. This is the link to the current tutorial that I am working on: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253009/after-creating-the-tutorial-package-beginner_tutorials,-the-package-cannot-be-found-later/) by [ChristianMoses](https://answers.ros.org/users/29165/christianmoses/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you remembered to `catkin_make` and also `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0